# How to Iterate through arithmetic operators across a static, excecutable formula in Python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to use itertools to iterate through mathematical operators.
Typically with an `array` of `[1, 2, 3]`, using `combinations` I can get the results:

```
1
1,2
1,3
2,3
1,2,3
```

etc.

I want to use this on an `array` of `[1, 2, 3]` in such a way that:

```
1+2+3
1+2-3
1+2/3
1+2*3
1-2+3
1-2-3
1-2/3
1-2*3
...
```

arises and gives results of the equation.

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: There are functions that perform the standard arithmetic operations in the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

Comment: There are two possible approaches: one is creating your formula as a string, then using `eval` to evaluate it; and another, to use functions from `operator` module.

Comment: Take a look at `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__` and `__div__` methods of `int`.

Comment: is it bound to only starting with addition and subtraction?

Comment: It's not bound for starting with anything in particular, it could go in any order.

Comment: One important question: do you want the operators to follow normal rules of precedence or just left-to-right? Ie., should the result of 1+2*3 be (1+2)*3=9 or 1+(2*3)=7?

Comment: @Błotosmętek I hadn't actually though that out. That certainly adds a layer of complexity to the use of the operators. In my case I would say I'm trying to achieve both, or as many answers as possible. But for the sake of this question, let's follow the normal rules of precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution generalized to any number of operands, and preserving normal precedence of operators:

```
from itertools import product

operands = [1, 2, 3, 4]
operators = [ '+', '*', '-', '//' ] # change '//' to '/' for floating point division
for opers in product(operators, repeat=len(operands)-1):
    formula = [ str(operands[0]) ]
    for op, operand in zip(opers, operands[1:]):
        formula.extend([op, str(operand)])
    formula = ' '.join(formula)
    print('{} = {}'.format(formula, eval(formula)))
```

Comment: This is really good. However by changing the '//' to a '/' it ends up with the same answer as'//'. So the division is slightly off.

Comment: Erm, do you use Python 2.x? In this case, yes, there is no difference between `/` and `//`, unless you add this: `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach it:

```
import itertools
import operator
```

First make the list of all possible combinations:

```
funcs = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.div]

combos = list(itertools.product(funcs, repeat=2))

>>[(<function operator.add>, <function operator.add>),
 (<function operator.add>, <function operator.sub>),
 (<function operator.add>, <function operator.mul>),
 (<function operator.add>, <function operator.div>),
 (<function operator.sub>, <function operator.add>),
 (<function operator.sub>, <function operator.sub>),
 (<function operator.sub>, <function operator.mul>),
 (<function operator.sub>, <function operator.div>),
 (<function operator.mul>, <function operator.add>),
 (<function operator.mul>, <function operator.sub>),
 (<function operator.mul>, <function operator.mul>),
 (<function operator.mul>, <function operator.div>),
 (<function operator.div>, <function operator.add>),
 (<function operator.div>, <function operator.sub>),
 (<function operator.div>, <function operator.mul>),
 (<function operator.div>, <function operator.div>)]
```

Then we will iterate through this list solving every possible outcome:

```
for fn in combos:
    print 'This combo {} yielded this result {}'.format(fn, fn[1](fn[0](*seq[:2]), seq[-1]))

This combo (<built-in function add>, <built-in function add>) yielded this result 6
This combo (<built-in function add>, <built-in function sub>) yielded this result 0
This combo (<built-in function add>, <built-in function mul>) yielded this result 9
This combo (<built-in function add>, <built-in function div>) yielded this result 1
This combo (<built-in function sub>, <built-in function add>) yielded this result 2
This combo (<built-in function sub>, <built-in function sub>) yielded this result -4
This combo (<built-in function sub>, <built-in function mul>) yielded this result -3
This combo (<built-in function sub>, <built-in function div>) yielded this result -1
This combo (<built-in function mul>, <built-in function add>) yielded this result 5
This combo (<built-in function mul>, <built-in function sub>) yielded this result -1
This combo (<built-in function mul>, <built-in function mul>) yielded this result 6
This combo (<built-in function mul>, <built-in function div>) yielded this result 0
This combo (<built-in function div>, <built-in function add>) yielded this result 3
This combo (<built-in function div>, <built-in function sub>) yielded this result -3
This combo (<built-in function div>, <built-in function mul>) yielded this result 0
This combo (<built-in function div>, <built-in function div>) yielded this result 0
```

Edit: Here is a way that follows the rules of operations

```
ops = ['+','-','*','/']

combos = list(itertools.product(ops, repeat=2))

for tup in list(itertools.product(combos, [seq])):
    print 'These operations {} evaluate to this ---> {}'.format(tup[0],eval(''.join(*zip(seq[0],tup[0][0],seq[1],tup[0][1],seq[-1]))))

These operations ('+', '+') evaluate to this ---> 6
These operations ('+', '-') evaluate to this ---> 0
These operations ('+', '*') evaluate to this ---> 7
These operations ('+', '/') evaluate to this ---> 1
These operations ('-', '+') evaluate to this ---> 2
These operations ('-', '-') evaluate to this ---> -4
These operations ('-', '*') evaluate to this ---> -5
These operations ('-', '/') evaluate to this ---> 1
These operations ('*', '+') evaluate to this ---> 5
These operations ('*', '-') evaluate to this ---> -1
These operations ('*', '*') evaluate to this ---> 6
These operations ('*', '/') evaluate to this ---> 0
These operations ('/', '+') evaluate to this ---> 3
These operations ('/', '-') evaluate to this ---> -3
These operations ('/', '*') evaluate to this ---> 0
These operations ('/', '/') evaluate to this ---> 0
```

Comment: So, you mean that `This combo (<built-in function sub>, <built-in function mul>) yielded this result -3` is 1 - 2 * 3 === 1 - 6 == -3? :) How about the priority of operations?)

Comment: Doesn't respects the [bodmas rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). 1+2*3 shouldn't result in  9.

Comment: yes you're right I didn't consider order of operations, one second I will revise

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it's a bit heavier than what I was looking for but I appreciate your effort.

Comment: added an approach that follows rules of operations

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant one (made on knee) but works, just to point out my logic.
The idea is to reduce the list one by one in correct order. E.g.:

Data: 1 * 2 + 3 * 4

- After Step 1 ( first * evaluated ): 2 + 3 * 4
- After Step 2 ( second * evaluated ): 2 + 12
- After Step 3 ( + evaluated ): 14

The code:

```
import operator
import itertools

data = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
operators_1 = [operator.mul, operator.div] # this operators have priority over that below
operators_2 = [operator.add, operator.sub]

def processOps(formula, data, operators):
    res_formula = list(formula)
    result = list(data)
    for op in formula:
        if op not in operators: continue

        i = res_formula.index(op)
        result = result[:i] + [op(result[i], result[i + 1])] + result[i + 2:]
        res_formula.remove(op)

        if len(result) == 1:
            break

    return (res_formula, result)

for f in itertools.product(operators_1 + operators_2, repeat=len(data)-1):
    result = list(data)
    formula = list(f)
    formula, result = processOps(formula, result, operators_1)
    formula, result = processOps(formula, result, operators_2)
    print f, result
```

**UDP** This updated logic handles cases like (1 * 2) + (3 / 4) correctly.

Comment: I'm getting some mistakes here. For:
(<built-in function div>, <built-in function mul>, <built-in function add>) [4.166666666666667]
where it should be 1/2*3+4, the answer should be 5.5

Comment: I saw your next edit, this works great. Thank you :)

Comment: @NameyMcNamo, Thank you too, for this question - it was really interesting for me to make it working)

Answer (score 0):

Use the corresponding functions in the `operator` module and iterate over pairs of them.

```
import itertools
import operator

ops = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.div]

for f1, f2 in itertools.product(*ops, repeat=2):
    print f1(array[0], f2(array[1], array[2]))
```

Now, if `array` can have an arbitrary length, it gets a bit tricker.

```
for operations in itertools.product(*ops, repeat=len(array)-1):
  result = operations[0](array[0], array[1])
  for op, operand in zip(operations[1:], array[2:]):
      result = op(result, operand)
  print(result)
```

The structure above avoids having to know the appropriate identity element for each operation.

If you want to obey precedence (as seems likely), you'll want to create an expression and evaluate it with `eval` (standard warnings apply).

```
for ops in itertool.product("+", "-", "*", "/", repeat=len(array)-1):
  expr = "%s%s%s" % (array[0], ops[0], array[1])
  for op, operand in zip(ops[1:], array[2:]):
    expr = "%s%s%s" % (expr, op, operand)
  result = eval(expr)
```

I leave it as an exercise to expand this to produce parenthesized expressions like `(1+2)*3` in addition to `1+2*3`.

Comment: Replace `len(array)` with `len(array)-1` - number of operators is one less than number of operands.

Comment: Thanks; something about `operations` and `array` being sliced with different starting indices in the call to `zip` made me thing something was wrong, but I didn't stop to think what.

Comment: I try running these but it says:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
I think it refers to the 2.

Comment: I always forget; `repeat` has to be specified as a keyword argument.